# Capture POST request to local variable in script

Tags: javascript, php, post

I have the javascript code below that POSTs a request, I then want to save the response to a local variable named sku, but it is not binding.

the variable sku remains an empty string.

```js
var sku = "";  //to be passed to server when filled
    
    var cookie_info = {
        number_nights: number_nights_cookie,
        number_travelers: number_travelers_cookie,
        type_traveler: type_traveler_cookie,
        departure_date: departure_date_cookie,
        country: country_cookie
    };
    
    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'https://azooree.com/wp-admin/php/sku-calculation.php',
         data: cookie_info,
         success: function(response) {               
            console.log('success', response);
            sku = response;
         },
         error: function() {
             console.log('error!');
             alert("[ERROR] Information lost, please try again. Thank you!");
         }
    });
    
    var basic = {
        info: sku + "LP" 
    };
```

Comment: You have this tagged in PHP as well. Are you wanting the JS answer or PHP answer ?

Comment: Your assignment to `basic` is happening before the response callback, and while `sku` is still empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of variable `sku` is being returned from your `POST` request which is asynchronous. That's why at the time of assigning the value of `sku` to `basic` - it will be empty.

You can easily update the value of `basic` either by using a callback function like below-

```
$.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: 'https://azooree.com/wp-admin/php/sku-calculation.php',
     data: cookie_info,
     success: function(response) {               
        console.log('success', response);
        sku = response;
        updateBasicValue(sku);
     },
     error: function() {
         console.log('error!');
         alert("[ERROR] Information lost, please try again. Thank you!");
     }
});
function updateBasicValue(sku) {
    basic = {
        info: sku+"LP"
    };
}
```

Or else, you can do whatever you need to do with the `sku` variable inside the `success` function of your AJAX request.

**UPDATE**
You also need to check for CORS issues if your request is being sent from any other domain or subdomain different than the one causing it. - (Thanks LordNeo)

Comment: Just add that he needs to check for CORS issues if the request is being sent from any other domain or subdomain different than the one causing it.

Comment: That does not seem to work. How do I make the script wait for the response before continuing?

Comment: @IgorSilveira The script cannot wait for the response - this is the way AJAX calls work. What do you need to do with your response?

Comment: I need to use to make a GET request

Comment: So you can write your `GET` request in the `updateBasicValue()` function in my example above.

Comment: I think I can do what I want if I respond to the request with an array. And perhaps it has better performance than a request inside the request ?

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by 'respond to the request with an array'. Also, performance-wise I don't think you can do much if you need to make a GET request based on the data you get from your POST request.